# Highlighting repetitions of comment character for prog-mode

Tags: highlighting

I have the following code that highlights lines made from semicolons in the case of lisp-interaction-mode.

```
(defface special-comment '((t (:background "orange"))))
(font-lock-add-keywords 'lisp-interaction-mode 
   '(("^\\s<\\s<\\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t)))
```

But whilst trying to extend this to `prog-mode`, the highlighting is not taking effect.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'prog-mode 
   '(("^\\s<\\s<\\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t)))
```

Comment: Font-lock keywords aren't inherited from the parent mode. What you could do is to define a hook for prog-mode that calls `font-lock-add-keywords` with `nil` as the first parameter, this adds the keywords to the current buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `font-lock-set-defaults` obtains keywords with `(assq major-mode font-lock-keywords-alist)`.
`major-mode` is directly used. So no inheritance between major modes is taken into account.

Mode `prog-mode` is never used directly but only as parent mode of other programming modes such as `emacs-lisp-mode`.
Thus `(font-lock-add-keywords 'prog-mode ...)` never has any effect.

You should use `prog-mode-hook` instead. The hooks of parent modes are run in order of inheritance.

Use `nil` as mode argument for `font-lock-add-keywords` to add the keywords indiscriminately to `font-lock-keywords`.

```el
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda ()
                (font-lock-add-keywords
                 nil
                 '(("^\\s<\\s<\\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t)))))
```

---

As [Lindydancer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/897/lindydancer) pointed out [in his comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73561/highlighting-repetitions-of-comment-character-for-prog-mode/73563#comment119578_73563) it is better to give the hook function its own symbol:

```el
(defun my-add-special-comment-keyword ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("^\\s<\\s<\\s<+$" 0 'special-comment t))))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-add-special-comment-keyword)
```

That makes its management easier. For an instance you can remove the hook with

```el
(remove-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my-add-special-comment-keyword)
```

and you can change the definition of `my-add-special-comment-keyword` without messing up `prog-mode-hook`.

Instead of adding the hook by `add-hook` you can also customize the variable `prog-mode-hook` via *Options* → *Customize Emacs* → *Specific Option*.

Comment: Just a note on the style: I would avoid adding lambdas to hooks. 1) If you look at the value of a hook the lambda makes them unreadable. 2) If you edit the hook and reevaluate the expression, *both* the new and the old version will be attached to the hook, which could be extremely confusing. A better approach is to define a function like `my-prog-mode-hook` and add it to the hook.

Comment: @Lindydancer Yes, I know. This was just to keep the answer concise. By the way, I didn't see your comment until I finished writing my reply (in Org). Since my answer has some more details I posted it anyway.

Comment: No worries, I often post a comment when I don't have time to write a full answer, and I'm just glad that you did. After all, the most important thing is to help people -- not to earn points... Thanks for the update, it was spot on!

Comment: @Lindydancer You wrote: "After all, the most important thing is to help people -- not to earn points...". That goes without saying. Even so, I wouldn't like it if someone copied my comment as an answer *without* adding anything substantial.